# Python 2.7 csv format incorrect

Tags: python, csv

I am currently trying to write a list of scores called scores_int to a csv file. I want to make my csv file in this format:

https://gyazo.com/225685fc5e2d71426791ef55c92007d0

but it is currently being written in this format:

https://gyazo.com/8b1e374b6601f5a4025365975383c8c7

Here is my code for the write:

```
with open("srt_Scores.csv", "w") as sortfile:   #Should write a new csv file every time containing the sorted scores
    w = csv.writer(sortfile, delimiter = ",")
    w.writerows([[v] for v in scores_int])

crashed = True
```

If anyone could help me it would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Can we see `scores_int` please? Maybe it has genuine gaps, or elements that end in a newline.

Comment: Can you post the input and output csv files here instead of links to screenshots of a spreadsheet.

Comment: It doesnt have spaces, the problem has been fixed by the open mode to "wb" instead of "w"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "wb" instead of "w" because you need to open it as a binary file.

```
with open("srt_Scores.csv", "wb") as sortfile:   #Should write a new csv file every time containing the sorted scores
    w = csv.writer(sortfile, delimiter = ",")
    w.writerows([[v] for v in scores_int])

crashed = True
```